# Pig Latin Punctuation

Tags: bash, shell, loops, if-statement, sed

I have a file which takes the text of another file and converts it to pig latin, and it works fine, except that punctuation in words like:

`what's` becomes `atwhay'say` instead of what I want which would be for

`what's` to become `at'swhay`.

Code:

```
echo $(
for i in `cat $1`
do
    if [[ $i =~ ^[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ] ]]
    then
        echo $i | sed -e 's/\(\<[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]\+\)\([[:alpha:]]\)\([[:alpha:]]*\>\)/\U\2\L\3\L\1ay/g'
    elif [[ $i =~ ^[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz] ]]
    then    
        echo $i | sed -e 's/\(\<[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]\+\)\([[:alpha:]]*\>\)/\2\1ay/g'
    else
        echo $i | sed -e 's/\(\<[[:alpha:]]*\>\)/\1yay/g'
    fi
done
)
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this punctuation error

Comment: Change `[[:alpha:]]*` to `[[:alpha:]'\'']*` -- yes including a single quote in a single quoted string is ugly.

Comment: What's with the unnecessary outer `echo`?

Comment: The outer `echo` is to keep the text file from being output in a return-delimited list, since I would like to keep it's original formatting as best as I can. I can't think of a better way to do that.
Thank you! the change worked and I was able to apply it to the other punctuation as well.